# Recover lost data git?

Tags: git, git-merge

After merging feature branches in local (with master) and pushing to remote, an already completed feature lost from master(remote).Is there anyway to recover that lost files?

Comment: There's no verb in the first sentence. What is the lost data you want to recover?

Comment: @RomainValeri lost data means some angular files/component for a feature

Comment: Not any clearer. Sorry, I tap out until a better description.

Comment: @RomainValeri lost data means some html,typescript and some css files

Comment: The nature of these files is irrelevant here. Might as well be .avi videos, would be the same. My question was : can you clarify where these files come from, what you did, how you merged, and so on.

Comment: What does "recover" mean? Revert the merge? Return a deleted file? Undo a file change? Any combination of the above?

Comment: The data was almost certainly not lost; it was just superseded by a commit in which those changes/files are  not present.  If the situation is urgent I suggest you hire a consultant knowledgeable in `git` to fix up the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go back in the git history. E.g.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~N
```

where `N` is number of the recent commits you want to discard. The `--soft` parameter will keep changes from the remote repo locally on stage. You can also use `--hard` parameter to remove changes completely (you can always pull them from the remote repo).

Another option is to browse your gitlog with `git log` command, find a commit, which points to the state before crucial change was made  (you can use `grep` to filter commit messages) and checkout to this commit with the command

```
git checkout COMMIT_HASH
```

where `COMMIT_HASH` is your commit hash

After going back in the history, try to find your lost code. Then, you can either copy it somewhere, perform the `git reset --hard`, `git pull`, paste it in the latest source and perform a new commit or try to use cherry pick feature of the git.

**Please note**, proposed solutions will be feasible only if recent pushes didn't override the repo history (it could happen in the case of push with `--force` parameter) or they did, but you haven't pulled them yet.

Moreover, remember that **git is distributed VCS**, so in the case of push with force and pull, you can try to find a colleague from your team, who haven't done the pull and recover history from his local repo.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is not clear before seeing a tree or merge commands.

But you can always use git reflog in the local repository who perform merges. You'll see a version of repository before the merge. Assuming that feature/files are on a branch or easy to add into a separate branch; you can simply create a new feature branch from there and push it to remote. While merging newly created branch back to master, probably it'll do the same thing. So it's better to rebase new branch on top of master